# The integrations channel names are not what I think I configured. What gives?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

It appears that the channel name is being concatenated with the toString() result of the application wrapper to create the actual channel name.

1. Does this matter?
2. Does this have anything to do with the "Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel" error I am chasing?
3. If so, what do I do about it?
4. If not, how do I find the actual error I am chasing?

The name of the channel, according to the exception that is being thrown, is 
:

```
org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext@78e22c75.outbound-requests
```

My code is:

```
@Bean(name="outbound-requests")
public MessageChannel outboundRequestsChannel() {
    MessageChannel result = new DirectChannel();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is not correct. The channel name is what you give it.In the end it's _a been_ as any other.  But without seeing your exception I am not sure what problem you are having.

Comment: I figured out the exception - the outboundChannelAdapter needs to be wrapped with an @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outbound-requests") annotation to link the DirectChannel to the final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, this matters. Your application may have several application contexts. Let's say parent/child relationship and your "children" may have the same bean name. So, login just a bean name without application context id. The relavant code is like this:

   ```
   /**
    * Returns the fully qualified channel name including the application context
    * id, if available.
    *
    * @return The name.
    */
    public String getFullChannelName() {
       if (this.fullChannelName == null) {
           String contextId = getApplicationContextId();
           String componentName = getComponentName();
           componentName = (StringUtils.hasText(contextId) ? contextId + "." : "") +
                   (StringUtils.hasText(componentName) ? componentName : "unknown.channel.name");
           this.fullChannelName = componentName;
       }
       return this.fullChannelName;
   }
   ```
2. No, it doesn't. Such an exception means that there is no subscribed endpoint to this channel at the moment a message has been sent. Or you just don't have this channel as an `input` one anywhere or an endpoint has been stopped in between.
3. Investigate where you use this channel as an input one or how it is possible that your possible endpoint is stopped.
4. There is no way from the Framework perspective to determine what you would like to do with this channel. A `DirectChannel` is that kind of channel implementation that requires a subscriber to be active before a message is sent to this channel.

I answered to all your question, but it is still not clear what is the goal you are pursuing sharing with us all this info.

In two word: have a subscriber to this channel and your `Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel` will go! In other words it is about a `@ServiceActivator`, `@Transformer` or relevant XML configuration or even Java DSL `IntegrationFlow`.

To solve your real problem we need to see more configuration around that `outbound-requests` channel definition.

Comment: Thank you again Artem. On a hunch I put an @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outbound-requests") annotation on the KafkaProducerMessageHandler bean, and messages are being sent finally. If I understand this part of your answer, the @ServiceActivator annotation provides the binding between the channel and the adapter.

Comment: Regarding the name  - I can read this expanded name, knowing my application, and know that I am looking at a global scoped bean named "outbound-requests". The expanded name matters in some contexts, but not for the issue I was chasing.

Comment: That's correct. See here for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#programming-tips

Comment: Thank you. I have read and re-read that chapter and, unfortunately, am having difficulty making any sense of it.

Comment: M-m-m. You know, it sounds like we are leaking something in our Docs. Please, raise a GH issue with ideas what you would like to see there which would be helpful for your as well as for any newcomers.

Comment: I will do that. And again, thank you for your kind assistance.